# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Sending Data Extracts to Another (non-SFMC) SFMC Site

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

Is it possible for Salesforce Marketing Cloud to send a data extract (from a data extension) from SFMC Safehouse location at the business unit's sFTP to a completely different sFTP site located on another company system/server? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to setup external SFTP locations. Just go to:

`Email Studio > Admin > Data Management > File Locations`

[Here's the official documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_file_locations.htm&type=5) on the subject and a screen how it looks like in the interface:

[image]

In your Automation you'll need to do the Data Extract and then use a File Transfer activity to transfer your file your new external file location.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!